# How can I fix navigation bar on top when page moves?

Tags: java, spring, web, layout

I'm making a small web site with Spring framework and It has a few menus on navigation bar (with bootstrap). and each menu is written in different file. so when it's clicked, the changes shouldn't be the menu on navigation bar but the contents only.

what I have done is using `<a>`tag to move to each page but in this case, whole page reloads for each click.
*(move to the new page link)*

What I want to make is displaying navigation bar on top all the time and when I click one of the menus, it only changes the other parts.

should I type the same code for navigation bar on every menu's page?
or is there a kind of template as 'jinja' with python?

Comment: try to give code sample or example.

Comment: Thank for the answers. Actually all the answers that I've already known. I wanted to use page changing. For example, using Jinja2 template of python flask. I solved with it.

Answer (score 0):

set this method 

 add this to your navigation bar CSS class

```
position:fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap you need only use this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> //gives a dark background #222 by default
```

or

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> //gives a light background with darker shaded border
```